# Hibernate - Many to many implementation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have 3 tables, Playlist, Song and Playlist_Song. Playlist_Song has a playlist_id foreign key and a user_id foreign key. I need to get a list of songs in a specific playlist so I thought to make a database call to Playlist_Song that returns all entries with a playlist_id.

I then use the song ids to make database calls to the song table in order to retrieve those songs. I feel like this is highly inefficient and there should be a better way, but I don't really know how to do that. Any suggestions?

```
  public List<Song> getSongsInPlaylist(final int playlistId) {

  final List<PlaylistSong> playlistSongs = playlistSongDao.getPlaylistSong(playlistId);

  if (!playlistSongs.isEmpty()) {
     final List<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>();
     for (PlaylistSong existingPlaylistSong : playlistSongs) {
        songs.add(songDao.findById(existingPlaylistSong.getSongId()).get());
     }

     return songs;
  }
```

Comment: Does `Playlist_Song` have a PK?

Comment: @PeterRader Playlist_Song is a join table for the relation so the PK is created with the combination of the two FK (Playlist, Song)

Comment: Do you use Audit or Enver on the tables?

Answer (score 0):

Pass as a list of song ids, to the songDao and retrieve as a list in one query.
songDao.findByIdIn(List songIds).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for using dao and accessing join table for such simple implementations. If you define your models like this you should be able to access songs in a playlist with simple getSongs() method defined on the Playlist model.

Song model:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Song {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column (name = "title")
    private String title;

    // some other properties...

    @ManyToMany (mappedBy = "songs")
    private List<Playlist> playlists = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Playlist model:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Playlist {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    // some other properties...

    @ManyToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable (
            name = "Playlist_Song",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn (name = "playlist_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn (name = "song_id") }
    )
    private List<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And to get a specific Playlist using only Hibernate (though this is easier with Spring repositories if you're using those) you can get it by using Session object.

```
public Playlist getPlaylistById(Integer id) {
    Playlist playlist = null;

    try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()){
        playlist = (Playlist) session.get(Playlist.class, id);
    }

    return playlist;
}
```

Comment: can you explain how this works?
previously, I was making n calls to the database to populate my song arraylist,
but with this new implementation, does this make it so there's 1 call to the database?
if so, how does that work?

I see that getSongs would get the list of songs, but how does it get populated?
isn't that still n calls to the database to get all songs?

Comment: @DJG upon what do you need clarification exactly? This lets Hibernate create calls to the database so in my opinion it should be OK unless you need some very performant solution. I think that behind the scenes there are two calls to the database: 1. when you select a playlist by id, 2. when you use getSongs() method. That should be two calls (two SELECT statements) to the database though it is possible JPA optimizes them into one call (not sure).

Comment: how getSongs works with this table.
when does this songs list get populated with songs?

Comment: well it depends how you define association on the Playlist model. If you set eager fetch all songs for that playlist will be loaded when you load Playlist entity and you can use the populated list by calling getSongs method. But if you set lazy fetch the songs will be loaded when you call getSongs method.

Comment: how does getSongs work under the hood, though?
can you explain how this join table and join column works?
in relation to what I was doing previously and how this solves my problem of inefficiency?

Comment: For reference on the annotations check JPA documentation. It solves your problem because you don't have to do N select statements anymore but maximally two (depending on the fetch option): on for selecting the Playlist entity by the id and one for fetching all songs that have that playlist id in the join table (Playlist_Song) which is just one SQL statement instead of n.